# mysql c++ connector setBlob() fails

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a table my_table with fields

```
id, INT, auto_increment
field_one, varchar(64)
field_two, tinytext
field_three, longblob
```

when trying to insert I use the following code

```
sql::PreparedStatement *prepared_statement = this->connection_->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO my_table(field_one,field_two,field_three) VALUES ('one','two',?)");
std::ifstream file_stream("myfile");
prepared_statement->setBlob(3, &file_stream);
```

I get MySQL_Prepared_Statement::setBlob: invalid 'parameterIndex'

this->connection_ is valid, the prepared_statement is not NULL, and the file stream is open

documentation on the connector classes seems lacking.
any suggestions?
Thank You!

Comment: interesting, if I change the index used to 1, it seems to work correctly.  I guess I am not clear on what this index signifies.  I thought it meant the 1 based index in the INSERT list.  I will investigate further